# R Plot Histogram On Dataframe with dates-time object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following R dataframe with column Date and column Value, column Date is R chron objects (format <- "m/d/y h:m:s").

What I want to do is to visualize the time series data by ploting histogram or line chart, and I also want to specify the date-time range on x-axis (e.g. from 10/2/16 20:00:00 to 10/3/16 20:00:00). However after searching for the online guides I still do not have a clue.

Would anyone give me a sample code using ggplot or other package? I appreciate your help.

```
Date                 Value
(10/03/16 09:31:00)  180,912.00
(10/03/16 09:32:00)  112,359.00
(10/03/16 09:35:00)   93,539.00
(10/03/16 09:35:00)  156,283.00
(10/03/16 09:36:00)  226,704.00
(10/03/16 09:37:00)  780,094.00
(10/03/16 09:45:00)  184,632.00
(10/03/16 09:48:00)  144,984.00
(10/03/16 09:49:00)  311,035.00
(10/03/16 09:51:00)  210,653.00
(10/03/16 09:51:00)   72,626.00
(10/03/16 09:52:00)  241,173.00
(10/03/16 09:54:00)  233,416.00
(10/03/16 09:55:00)  146,550.00
(10/03/16 10:24:00)  331,191.00
(10/03/16 10:28:00)  107,015.00
(10/03/16 10:36:00)  196,162.00
(10/03/16 10:41:00)  466,879.00
(10/03/16 10:44:00)  294,589.00
(10/03/16 10:48:00)  164,339.00
(10/03/16 10:52:00)  137,082.00
(10/03/16 10:58:00)  180,667.00
(10/03/16 11:04:00)  259,475.00
```

---

Updated on 11/28/2016 6:35 pm
With the help of yeedle's codes, I am able to plot the following:

> ggplot(temp_merge_sub1, aes(x=Date, y=Value,
>   group=1)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")

[GGPlot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmZk4.jpg)

What I really want to improve from that is:

- how to correctly set the breaks on y-axis?
- how to set breaks on x-axis and display the histogram on the added up value in each of the 2-hour intervals?

Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: can you post the `dput` output of your df?

Comment: You have multiple values for the same date-time. How do you want that to be displayed on the plot?

Comment: Thank you @yeedle for helping with my question. The data above is only a small portion of my data, and what I would like to show with histogram is kind of adding up the value within certain fixed time ranges (e.g. 2 hour breaks, 10/3/2016 6:00 - 8:00, 8:00-10:00, ... etc) and then how the histogram of added up value over each of the time intervals. I am not sure if ggplot2 could do that?

Comment: To do that you would can add a new column to your dataframe with the rounded time range (you can use the `round_date` function from `lubridate`), and then plot using the new column. Setting breaks and limits is done with `scale_x_datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted Date to `POSIXct` objects, using `lubridate`'s `ymd_hms` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_x_datetime(limits =c(mdy_hms("10/2/16 20:00:00"),mdy_hms("10/3/16 20:00:00")))
```

[image: bar plot with 1-day scale]

You get a clearer picture without the `scale_x_datetime` limits:

[image: bar plot with no scale limits]

Simply replace `geom_bar` with `geom_line` for a line graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image: line plot]

Comment: Or use `geom_col` instead.

Comment: It's new yes. It's equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.